# Extracting ldd --version with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, glibc, ldd

I am trying to verify the glibc version by extracting the `ldd --version` output. Here is an example from a Ubuntu machine:

```
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.21-0ubuntu4) 2.21
```

And here is another from a CentOS 6.5 machine:

```
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
```

Thank you,

Chris

Comment: Do you want `2.21` and `2.17` as output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ ldd --version | awk '/ldd/{print $NF}'
2.19
```

Basically, if the line contains the string `ldd`, print the last field.

Comment: The best way to see the glibc version on your system is  executing the libc.so file, as weird as it seems:

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to discover the libc version you are using is executing the `libc.so`  file. Yes, it is weird, but this is how you should do, `ld --version` as `ldconfig --version` is not the right way.

```
$ /lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.21-0ubuntu4) stable release version 2.21, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.9.2.
Available extensions:
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bugs>.
```